# App package for Hololens on dev center

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to upload an app but it was refused on the dev center for showing a problem due to dll's that can't be used. It claims to need the .NET native to be ticked.

But when .NET native is set on, I get mismatch between the processor architecture being AMD64 and the reference being x86. This is while generating the package in VS.

I do not have AMD64 ticked when creating the package and the platform target in Build settings is x86. I also have Release selcted in the Build.

Configuration manager shows x86 with Release.

What is going on?
Thanks

EDIT: So I realized that I was uploading the wrong file, it should be the appxupload. But the main problem is that I do not have that file though I ticked the box to upload to the store and I have associated my account.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an app package and choose **(Yes) build package upload to the Windows Store**, finally you could find **[AppName]\AppPackages** in the root of your solution, and it will end with the **.appxupload** file extension.

You could follow [**these steps**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) to check if you have some errors in your creating app package process. If you still experience the same issue, please provide more details for me so that I can help your better.